# JqGrid - Add events on addRow fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jqgrid

Using jqGrid,  is there any way to update the values of a select field once the add Form dialog has been loaded? I need to update the list of values on the select field based on data the user is entering on a another field in the same add Form dialog.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is the model structure I have

```
{name:"Name",index:"Name", width:30,editable: true,editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},
{name:'LastName',index:'LastName', width:30,editable: true,editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},
{name:'Id',index:'Id',width:30, editable:true, sorttype:"text",editoptions:{size:"30",maxlength:"30"}},
{name:'Email',index:'Email', width:40, editable: true,editoptions:{size:"40",maxlength:"30"}, editrules:{custom:true, custom_func:emailFormatter}},
{name:'Option1',index:'Option1', width:20, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:updateOption1Values}}
```

I figured out how to attach an event to the Id field.

```
afterShowForm: function (e) {
    $("input#Id").blur(function() {
        updateOption1Values();
          $("input#Option1").selectmenu("refresh");
        alert("Blur!");
    });
}
```

Now what I need is to update the Option1 select box. I call updateOption1Values and manipulate the values but the select control is not showing those changes

Comment: [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow) is the method of **inline editing**. It creates no dialog. Probably you mean [Add form](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#adding_row)? Do you want to do something on opening of the dialog or when the user click Submit button and the data will be saved to the server?

Comment: You are right, Oleg. It is "add Form". My bad.
Actually,I need to update the values of select fields on the dialog based on data the user is entering on the same dialog. Lets say, the user enters a  Country and then I call an ajax method to get the states of the that Country and feed that data to a select field

Comment: If you use "Add" form then you add new row. If you saves the results to the server then the grid will be reloaded after submit (see default option `reloadAfterSubmit: true` of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties)) which creates the editing dialog. How exactly you use Add form? Do you use `navGrid`? With which parameters? Which `datatype` have the grid? Do you use `loadonce: true`? Which version of jqGrid or free jqGrid you use? You should append the text of your question with more details or code fragments.